# VBA count consecutive non-empty cells in a column, starting from a given one: must handle special cases

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulties with a seemingly trivial task. I'm writing a function which, starting from a cell, counts all consecutive non-empty cells (**including** the first one), or stops before in case an optional Ncells number of cells has been reached. That's what I cooked up:

```
Function CountCells(Row As Long, Column As Long, Optional Ncells As Variant, _
Optional sht As Worksheet) As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim xlsht As Worksheet
'
'           set target worksheet
'
If sht Is Nothing Then
   Set xlsht = ActiveSheet
Else
   Set xlsht = sht
End If
If IsMissing(Ncells) Then
   Ncells = xlsht.Rows.Count
End If

With xlsht
   I = .Cells(Row, Column).End(xlDown).Row
   If I > Ncells Then I = Ncells
End With

CountCells = I - Row + 1

End Function
```

It looked nice to me, but it does fail spectacularly if the first cell below the starting cell xlsht.Cells(Row, Column) is empty. I'd like CountCells to return 1 in this case, but instead it returns the number of consecutive empty cells down to the first non-empty one, or the end of the column. The same result is obtained if the starting cell is empty; in this case, I would say that the user is using the function the wrong way, but let's say that the return value must be 0.

EDIT a user requested an example. Since it looks like spreadsheets can't be attached to posts, I'm giving a link to Google Drive https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxB-VPeuApOkeThFZUJ3X2hyTGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm finding your description hard to understand. Could you supply an example please? Also would you except a spreadsheet formula or do you specifically need VBA?

Comment: I absolutely need VBA. I'd be happy to provide an example, but is there a way to attach a spreadsheet to the question?

Answer (score 2):

`.End(xlDown)` has same behavior as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd>.

When you are in last cell in a non-empty area, cursor will jump to first cell of following non-empty area.

You must handle this case:

```
If row > Ncells Then
   If xlsht.Cells(Row+1, Column).Value = Empty Then
       CountCells = 1
       Exit Function
   End If
```

End If

Note that name `Ncells` induce in error, it is really a `MaxRow`.

Comment: Hmmm, I would need to handle also the case where `xlsht.Cells(Row+1, Column)` is empty. This is a solution, but I'd prefer a solution which doesn't have to handle two special cases. If this is impossible using `End(xlDown).Row`, I'd gladly accept solutions based on other methods (except of course a `For...Next` on all cells).